# Access parent controller from ng-included HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access a function in a controller from an ng-included html, which contains a directive with an html template.

Meaning, given parent html template with controller:

```
<div ng-controller="profileCtrl">
    <div ng-include src="profileContent"></div>
</div>
```

**profileCtrl:**

```
$scope.profileContent = '/html/views/myview.html';
$scope.test = 'This should show';
```

**myview.html:**

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

**myDirective:**

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/html/directives/myDirectiveTemplate.html',
            ...
```

**myDirectiveTemplate.html:**

```
{{test}} //should output "This should show"
```

How can I access $scope.test from the child myDirective?

---

**myDirectiveTemplate.html:**

```
<form ng-submit="$parent.updateProfile()">
```

**profileCtrl:**

```
    $scope.updateProfile = function() {
        console.log('updating profile'); //not called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
{{$parent.test}}
```

Comment: Okay great! However I actually wanted to call a function on `ng-submit` from that child directive on a function within that parent controller. `$parent.test` outputs just fine, but if I call `updateProfile`, it won't run. See above

Comment: can you provide a plunkr for this ?

Comment: Anik, found my issue. I was wrapping my directive form in a bootstrap accordion. This accordion captures the scope within it, meaning I needed to do $parent.$parent.ctrlFunction() to access the function within the controller.